# Should I post a new question if there is an exact duplicate that has an accepted answer that does not answer the question?

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions, xy-problem

The question I have is, [How to get the item count of a CharacterSet in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460298/how-to-get-item-count-of-a-characterset-in-swift). It was pointed out that it is most likely an example of an "XY Problem," which the OP agreed it was, and has an accepted answer that does solve the "X" problem in his case, but it isn't a usable solution for me. (Of course, it is also very likely that I am simply trying to solve a different "X" problem that I am not able to see)

What should I do in this case? Post the exact same question asking how to solve "Y" but with different context? Edit the existing question to add my scenario? (This doesn't feel like a very "polite" thing to do, for lack of a better word)

Should I keep thinking and try identify my "X" problem and come up with a coherent way to ask about how to solve it? I feel I am lacking in skill and/or experience to do this any time soon though, at least on my own.

Comment: *"has an accepted answer that does solve the "X" problem in his case, but it isn't a usable solution for me."* Then by definition, it's not an exact duplicate, because if it were then the exact same answer would apply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

##### Post a new question

Duplicates are for when *the same answer applies to your question*. Sometimes an issue can appear to be one issue, when it is really another. Just make sure none of the duplicate answers really do apply.

##### Explicitly talk about why this is not a duplicate

Mention the other question and then explain the differences, or why the other answer(s) did not apply to this problem. This signals to other users that you've done some homework and should help you avoid duplicate closure.

##### It still might be a duplicate

Sometimes users *think* they have found something unique, when they just didn't look at the problem correctly. Be prepared that someone might poke a hole in your non-duplicate theory.

Comment: Thank you, though it’s a bit late. The advice was helpful on many SE sites, not just SO