# (How) should one defend against the "dual XY problem" properly when posting a question?

Tags: discussion, edits, xy-problem

### Background

From my experience, both when asking my own questions and when finding past questions and answers, a major bane of SO is the infamous so-called "[XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)" - and not technically the XY problem itself, namely when people ask about the wrong thing, but more precisely a dual problem I don't know (if there's) a term for: when people accuse the OP of XY (sometimes consciously and explicitly, sometimes not) and *answer something else*.

In my experience, this is problematic in two ways:

- When searching for information on something I sometimes stumble upon questions very similar to my own. But often the answers (including accepted and highly positively voted answers) don't answer the question at all, but something else. This significantly hinders the process of searching for the information I need, and on top of it it hinders the process of asking new questions about it, because superficially these new questions appear to be duplicates and to already have been answered.
- When asking my own questions, I often get answers to other things (because those answering think they know better what my *real* problem is), which are far from satisfactory (because actually my real problem is exactly what I asked), and the discussions that arise are often unpleasant, and add a lot of noise.

### My take

#### When answering

I think that for the benefit of the quality (ease of search/navigation/use) of the mountains of Q&As we're constantly generating for posterity, *answers should always answer the question asked*. When someone suspects a given question is an instance of the XY problem, the right way to deal with it is to *comment* about it (not answer!), and ideally refer to other places where what they think the real problem is is discussed, or if there aren't enough references then encourage the OP to *open another question* and ask about the other problem if that's what they actually need. And then they can answer *there*. (And if they really want to provide an answer right away, and there's really no other information around to refer to, they might even post what they think is the right question on their own, and answer it, and refer to it. The important thing is that the answer is posted on a matching question, not on a different question.)

#### When asking

Something I've seen others do which I like a lot, and I think is a good principle in life in general, is being explicit. If all users acted as suggested above when answering questions, this wouldn't be necessary, but as it's not the case (yet), I find it extremely helpful to state explicitly that I'm seeking answers to what I've asked and not "answers" which tell me that I actually need to do something else altogether, and that if someone does think that's the case, they're welcome to write it *in comments*.

It adds effort to posting a question (theoretically it also means the question has more text to read which is also some burden to anyone reading it afterwards, but it's only a couple of sentences), but I think it is worth it so long as users providing answers don't act according to the guidelines above.

**Clarification:** All this is *my own opinion*. I don't know if there's a consensus about it among experienced users, and if that consensus, if it exists at all, matches my take. And I don't know if there are any pertinent official guidelines and what they are.

### Recent event

I recently posted a question, and, in accordance with what's explained above, I added an "anti-XY-accusation" note. Shortly after, another user edited my question and removed that note (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65349747/revisions).

### Questions

So what I'd like to ask/discuss is:

1. Does the community agree with my impressions (as detailed under *Background* above)?
2. Does the community agree with my approach (as detailed under *My take* above)?
3. Does the community agree with the edit (mentioned under *Recent event* above)? If so, does the community think I should just do away with such notes in the future, or may (or even should) I include such notes but word them differently? (Part of the problem is that the reasoning behind the edit is not mentioned. I don't know if the editor thinks running into the issues above is desired, or if he thinks it doesn't happen often enough to justify such a note, or if he found my language too harsh, or what. Which brings about another issue: how to deal with edits in general. Comments with relevant references welcome!)

Comment: The edit was perfectly appropriate and yes you should refrain from such commentary in the question. If you get answers that you don't feel directly address your  problem then comment on that specific answer. If you commonly get answers that don't address what you think the question is, then perhaps you aren't being specific enough  outlining the problem(s)

Comment: You see, the answers aren't actually for you, they are for everyone in the future. You can choose to downvote and not mark an answer as correct. However, taking the liberty to control what might work for other people in the future is possibly a step to far. The problem with X/Y problems is they ***are*** common first assumptions of how to fix a problem you shouldn't be having, seasoned developers and users pick up on this and try to work out the exact nature of the problem, if they choose to answer an alternative solution, that is there choice...

Comment: Also a large subset of the problems that help me on the site are not actually the accepted answer for one reason or another, and I am certain at one point or another there has been an out of the box solution that would have helped me that was answering the X/Y nature of a problem i was trying to solve.

Comment: @charlietfl: I agree that in an _ideal_ world - one not rife with the "dual XY problem", commenting on specific answers would be the right way to go. But, at least from my experience, we're far from there, which is why I find it useful to help prevent that situation in advance. As for "perhaps you aren't being specific enough", I think that's plainly not the case, and, in fact, such notes like the one removed in the edit serve specificity! How can you both suggest I might not be specific enough, and suggest the removal was appropriate? I find it somewhat contradictory.

Comment: @TheGeneral: You're totally right about the answers being for everyone in the future, and about it indeed often being helpful to provide a solution to the _real_ problem, which is not necessarily what OPs ask. The problem is this is extremely unhelpful for future readers whose problem actually is the one explicitly asked about. Wouldn't it be better _for everyone_ if answers _always_ addressed the question asked, with the "real" question that should have been asked posted and answered somewhere else (which should, of course, be referenced)?

Comment: The commentary that was removed by edit was not problem related, it was your rules on how answers should work. Having reviewed many tens of thousands of questions over the years that is a highly unusual practice. The community sets the standards for answers. There are no contradictions in my comment above. Without any examples I don't agree with your whole dual XY perceived issue either as a general site wide problem

Comment: *"Wouldn't it be better for everyone if answers always addressed the question asked"* . Provide some examples where that isn't the case. Yes it happens but in very very small scale. In my experience the majority of the time when it occurs comments in the vane of "*How does this answer the question?"* are added to such answers

Comment: I recommend you get into the following habit when you see something like that and ask yourself this: is it more likely that unlike the last 1,000 people that asked this and it was totally an XY problem I really do have problem X...or is it that *my mental model is* **wrong**? Now, I'm not saying that it never happens, but I run across questions, often several in the course of the 5 minutes I spend here while something is compiling/downloading, where people are **clearly** stuck on their (inappropriate) solution instead of the actual problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Sure, it might very well be that someone - and thousand of others like them - ask X when their real problem is Y. But even in that case I'd argue it does more bad than good to post an answer to Y as an answer to X, instead of commenting that the actual problem might be Y and referring to somewhere else where Y is asked and answered (creating that place if necessary - but as a separate, Y-focused post, not as a discussion of X). Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Here's an example I happened to stumble upon of how providing an answer which solves an OP's real problem helps the OP - and possibly others - but hurts the community: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398722/777775. Again, I don't advocate for not providing users with the real solution they really need - I just think it would be extremely more helpful if answers to Y were not posted as answers to X, even when Y is the OP's real problem.